# Git Ignored File When GitIgnore Doesn't Exist

Tags: ios, xcode, git, branch, git-commit

I have an iOS project on XCode. I've been working off of a branch for some time. I've made particular changes to a file and have been committing the branch for some time. When I moved to an old branch, merged the code, and deleted the most recent branch, I realized this file was never updated to Git. I don't have a `.gitignore` file.

All my other files were pushed except for this particular set of header and main Objective-C files. I have no idea why the code was never pushed up. I've spent quite a bit of time working on this and losing this updated file is a great blow to me. When I moved to an older commit from the deleted branch the file took its original form.

What could have caused this and is there any wy for me to fix this?

**UPDATE**

This is not my first rodeo with git. Let me further explain.

Every commit I've made I've used `git add .` and followed up with `git commit` and `git push` respectfully.

I've attempted to pull the branch from the remote repository but the file does not reflect all of the changes I've made to it as of my most recent commit.

Comment: Firstly, were these files that weren't merged in new files? You need to do an explicit `git add` for newly created files.

Answer (score 0):

You second question - how do I get the code I had on the file that I just deleted.

Here's how -

Create a new branch -

```
git checkout -b newBranch
```

Perform a RefLog and get the commits from it -

```
git reflog | grep commit
```

Now, you should get a list of commits like this -

```
d2456b7 HEAD@{1}: commit   (merge): Merge
354dce1 HEAD@{3}: commit: 4
8c01ff7 HEAD@{6}: commit: 3
1ab4588 HEAD@{7}: commit: 2
3c419d5 HEAD@{8}: commit (initial): 1
```

Find the commits that you want, say `3` and `2` from above and do :

```
git cherry-pick 1ab4588
git cherry-pick 8c01ff7
```

Do this for all your commits and you should have your branch back.

Alternatively, if you pushed your branch, you could just pull it back.

```
git pull origin branchName
```

Comment: I've already attempted this exact solution and the file does not reflect my most recent changes to the file.

Comment: Did you commit those changes? As I stated, you need to explicitly stage new files for committing.

Comment: If you create a file and add it once. Any new changes to it will be staged for adding immediately. However, if it is a new file, then the above does not apply to it.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your update. What is the type of the file you are missing?

Comment: Objective-C .h and .m file. All other objective c files are accounted for.